# Get error: "Could not execute query" with session.Delete

Tags: nhibernate

Get error: "Could not execute query" with session.Delete.

When I copy the query and run it in SQL server Management studio the select query runs without an issue. Seems the problem is with the delete or something... I have deleting records from other tables using the same approach and seems to work fine.

Any ideas what's causing this?

The class:

```
    public class MultisitePublicBooking
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int multisiteID { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime startDate { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime startTime { get; set; }
    }

    public MultisitePublicBookingMap()
    {
        Table("tblMultisitePublicBooking");

        Id(x => x.Id).Column("PublicBookingID");
        Map(x => x.multisiteID).Column("MultisiteID");
        Map(x => x.startDate).Column("StartDate");
        Map(x => x.startTime).Column("StartTime");

    }
```

Table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblMultisitePublicBooking](
[PublicBookingID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MultisiteID] [int] NULL,
[NumAttendees] [int] NULL,
[AttendeeName] [varchar](1024) NULL,
[AttendeePhone] [varchar](128) NULL,
[AtendeeEmail] [varchar](500) NULL,
[BookingPrice] [money] NULL,
[LID] [int] NULL,
[TimeZoneID] [int] NULL,
[DateTimeModified] [datetime] NULL,
[DateTimeCreated]  AS (getdate()),
[CurrentStep] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[CallType] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
[CallSpeed] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[StartDate] [date] NULL,
[StartTime] [time](7) NULL,
[endtime] [time](7) NULL,
[Duration] [time](7) NULL,
[Catering] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[Equipment] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[Telepresence] [bit] NULL,
[telepresenceConfigOption] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Sync] [bit] NULL,
[ReceiveOrDial] [varchar](50) NULL,
[NoteTXT] [text] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblMultisitePublicBooking] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PublicBookingID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

The full error message is:
could not execute query

[ select multisitep0_.PublicBookingID as PublicBo1_18_, multisitep0_.MultisiteID as Multisit2_18_, multisitep0_.NumAttendees as NumAtten3_18_, multisitep0_.AttendeeName as Attendee4_18_, multisitep0_.AttendeePhone as Attendee5_18_, multisitep0_.AtendeeEmail as AtendeeE6_18_, multisitep0_.BookingPrice as BookingP7_18_, multisitep0_.LID as LID18_, multisitep0_.DateTimeModified as DateTime9_18_, multisitep0_.CurrentStep as Current10_18_, multisitep0_.CallType as CallType18_, multisitep0_.CallSpeed as CallSpeed18_, multisitep0_.StartDate as StartDate18_, multisitep0_.StartTime as StartTime18_, multisitep0_.Catering as Catering18_, multisitep0_.Equipment as Equipment18_, multisitep0_.Telepresence as Telepre17_18_, multisitep0_.telepresenceConfigOption as telepre18_18_, multisitep0_.Sync as Sync18_, multisitep0_.ReceiveOrDial as Receive20_18_, multisitep0_.NoteTXT as NoteTXT18_ from tblMultisitePublicBooking multisitep0_ where multisitep0_.MultisiteID=101156 ]
[SQL: select multisitep0_.PublicBookingID as PublicBo1_18_, multisitep0_.MultisiteID as Multisit2_18_, multisitep0_.NumAttendees as NumAtten3_18_, multisitep0_.AttendeeName as Attendee4_18_, multisitep0_.AttendeePhone as Attendee5_18_, multisitep0_.AtendeeEmail as AtendeeE6_18_, multisitep0_.BookingPrice as BookingP7_18_, multisitep0_.LID as LID18_, multisitep0_.DateTimeModified as DateTime9_18_, multisitep0_.CurrentStep as Current10_18_, multisitep0_.CallType as CallType18_, multisitep0_.CallSpeed as CallSpeed18_, multisitep0_.StartDate as StartDate18_, multisitep0_.StartTime as StartTime18_, multisitep0_.Catering as Catering18_, multisitep0_.Equipment as Equipment18_, multisitep0_.Telepresence as Telepre17_18_, multisitep0_.telepresenceConfigOption as telepre18_18_, multisitep0_.Sync as Sync18_, multisitep0_.ReceiveOrDial as Receive20_18_, multisitep0_.NoteTXT as NoteTXT18_ from tblMultisitePublicBooking multisitep0_ where multisitep0_.MultisiteID=101156]

The inner exception is:

```
{"Input string '20:00:00' was not in the correct format."}

    {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'."}
```

[image: screen shot of error message]

Comment: And what is the continuation of the error message and contents of any InnerException?

Comment: @OskarBerggren for some reason I didn't think to check that, I have updated the above with the full message and InnerException. Certainly seems like a clue... looking into it now...

Comment: The database field is of type 'time', where as the nHibernate object field type is DateTime, that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some problem with the mapping from TimeSpan to the SQL 'time' data type.

You can fix it by setting the startTime-property-mapping like so:

```
        Map(x => x.startTime).CustomType("TimeAsTimeSpan");
```

Once the mapping has been set properly you can also delete the specified record.

Answer (score 0):

you are right, the problem is in the sql server **Time** column mapping. You can read here more: [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/11/nhibernate-and-ms-sql-server-2008-date-time-datetime2-and-datetimeoffset.aspx)

The mapping in *xml* file will look like this:

```
<property name="StartTime" type="TimeAsTimeSpan" />
```

And the entity will be:

```
public class MultisitePublicBooking
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int MultisiteID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public virtual TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
}
```